# getting default value through constexpr

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T getDefault()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, CString>)
    {
        return "";
    }
}

template<typename T>
struct getdef
{
    static constexpr T value = getDefault<T>();
};
```

Now I want to get the default value for CString...CString is the class from MFC.

```
CString s2 = getDefault<CString>();
CString s = getdef<CString>::value;
```

The first line using getDefault correctly compiles, but the second one emits an error.

> Error C2127   'value': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with
>   a non-constant expression

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: CString is the class from MFC, too much to include. typedef ATL::CStringT< TCHAR, StrTraitMFC_DLL< TCHAR > > CString;

Comment: MFC classes don't have `constexpr` constructors to my knowledge. So you can't create `constexpr` objects of those types.

Comment: For instance, here's the same [case with `std::string`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f52af2b2021904e), made into a MCVE. It's not a literal type either.

Comment: I see, so only the function is usable for non primitive types. thanks

Comment: You can use it for non-primitive types. You just can't create `constexpr` objects of non-literal type.

Comment: Changing it to `constexpr auto getDefault()` compiles and might be good enough for your purposes. The type of the default value is different, but `CString` probably has proper constructors and comparison operators defined that it behaves well enough.

Comment: Side note: You do not return anything in the else case - I'd rather prefer a template specialisation then and leave the other cases unimplemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CString` does not have a `constexpr` constructor, hence, it cannot be used to initialize a `constexpr` object.

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite clear; Since classes such as `CString` do not have [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) constructors, they cannot be instantiated as `constexpr` variables.